# What is Geth's JIT VM?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, security, synchronization, jitvm

Whilst downloading the blockchain which has taken me approximately a week to get to block 1.09 mil, I received a message from geth.exe after a reboot around 1050999 -1060888

> You're one of the lucky few that will try out the JIT VM (random). If
>   you get a consensus failure please be so kind to report this incident
>   with the block hash that failed. You can switch to the regular VM by
>   setting --jitvm=false

*Any idea as to what this means ?*  It's a **Just In Time** Virtual Machine? after reading and reading I'm surmising this has to be some sort of fork? Correct me if I'm wrong , thanks for the feedback ! Due to my lizard brain I rebooted the sync.

Comment: I can't add humor and say "Won the Lotto?"  sheessk i guess, thanks for the reminder on the upvote . So say we all n'stuff

Comment: Not really :)  Our site currently now is quite loose compared to others, where things are really tightened, no room for "thanks" etc.  Example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1642028/revisions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have guessed, this is the new Just-In-Time virtual machine in the `geth` Ethereum node software.

From [go-ethereum - cmd/util/flags.go, lines 683 to 688](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/utils/flags.go#L683-L688):

```
jitEnabled := ctx.GlobalBool(VMEnableJitFlag.Name)
// if the jit is not enabled enable it for 10 pct of the people
if !jitEnabled && rand.Float64() < 0.1 {
    jitEnabled = true
    glog.V(logger.Info).Infoln("You're one of the lucky few that will try out the JIT VM (random). If you get a consensus failure please be so kind to report this incident with the block hash that failed. You can switch to the regular VM by setting --jitvm=false")
}
```

Only 10% of the `geth` instances running this new version of software will use this JIT VM, and this 10% is randomly chosen.

If there is a major fault in the new JIT VM implementation, 90% of the nodes will still continue mining the Ethereum blockchain. The fault can be reported and while being fixed, the JIT feature can be disabled from the `geth` command line using the parameter `--jitvm=false`.

If you want to see the message again, just restart `geth` repeatedly, and on average you should see this message 1 out of 10 restarts.

It is not a fork in the blockchain.

Here is an article on the new JIT VM - [Optimising the Ethereum Virtual Machine](https://medium.com/@jeff.ethereum/optimising-the-ethereum-virtual-machine-58457e61ca15#.58zkoudg0).

Comment: It's called A/B testing and ensures that we have a range of subjects that we can use if anything goes wrong :-) It ensures that, if anything goes to shit, we still enough people available that run "correctly". Additionally, here's an article about the JIT itself https://medium.com/@jeff.ethereum/go-ethereums-jit-evm-27ef88277520